# Google Apps Script: How to get the first four files in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am currently using the following code to retrieve a folder and the files within:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);  
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
```

If it is possible, I would like to create a variable containing only the first four files that the above code finds.

Thank you for your help,
Connor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after File objects instead of IDs:

```
function getFirstFourFiles(folderId) {
  var limit = 4;
  var output = [];
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext() && limit--) {
    output.push(files.next());
  }
  return output;
}
```

Usage:

```
var files = getFirstFourFiles(id);
```

Returns an array of file objects which you can then use, e.g:

```
var files = getFirstFourFiles(id);
files.forEach(function(file) {
  Logger.log(file.getName());
});

// Output:
// "Filename 1"
// "Filename 2"
// "Filename 3"
// "Filename 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by first 4.  If you mean sorted by last modified then this code should work.  It will give you an array with the Id's of the first 4 files:

```
function firstfour () {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);  
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var i=0;
  var contentsArray = [];

while (contents.hasNext() && i < 4) {
  var file = contents.next();
  contentsArray.push(file.getId());  //this is the array that will have the Id's of the first 4 files.
  i++
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and time!